# Delphi XE2 - No output files created when building project for OSX platform

Tags: macos, delphi, cross-platform, delphi-xe2

I have some problem which is stopping Delphi XE2 from building my project for the OSX platform. I've gone back to basics and created a brand new 'Hello World' console application project. The program compiles/builds/runs fine on the Win32 platform. I add OSX as a new platform for the project, and my remote profile is configured correctly and clicking 'Test Connection' confirms it can see my MacBook. Problem is when I activate the OSX platform, then click 'Build' (under Debug or Release) then the progress window appears as usual and no errors occur, but no output files are created and the 'OSX32' subfolder doesn't get created.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it - no idea how it got there but in Tools->Options->Environment Variables  I had an entry under 'User overrides' as follows :

PLATFORM = Win32

This meant the compiler was only ever building for Win32, regardless of which platform was currently activated.